# insert a string in the previous line and next line of a particular phrase/text

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I want to edit a bunch of files in a folder  using a script/command as follows.

Before :

```
.
.
upc_barrier
.
.
```

After inserting:

```
.
.
start = clock();
upc_barrier
end  = clock() ;
.
.
.
```

Could any of you help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind to use `perl`

```
perl -pi -e "s/upc_barrier/start = clock();\nupc_barrier\nend  = clock() ;/g" ALL_FILES
```

Comment: can i give this command directly on the command line ? I got the error "Can't open ALL_FILES: No such file or directory."

Comment: ... `ALL_FILES` to be replaced by files you want to replaced. If you just want to replace every files, replaced it to `*`

Answer (score 3):

​The sed version:

```
sed -i 's/\(upc_barrier\)/start = clock\(\);\n\1\nend = clock\(\);/' FILES
```

Obviously replace FILES with whatever files you wish to operate on. The -i operator tells sed to write the modified stream back to the file.

Comment: Don't need to use back references. sed has `&` which when used in the replacement text will be replaced with whatever you matched on like so: `sed 's/upc_barrier/start = clock();\n&\nend  = clock();/'`